# Filter rows of a dataframe based on certain conditions in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

While I was handling the dataframe in pandas, got some unexpected cells which consists values like-

| E_no | E_name |
| --- | --- |
| 6654-0984 | Elvin-Johnson |
| 430 | Fred |
| 663/547/900 | Banty/Shon/Crio |
| 87 | Arif |
| 546 | Zerin |
| 322,76 | Chris,Deory |

In some rows, more than one E_name and E_no has been assigned which is supposed to be a single employee in each and every cell
My data consists of E_no and E_name both these column needs to be separated in different rows.

What I want is

| E_no | E_name |
| --- | --- |
| 6654 | ELvin |
| 0984 | Johnson |
| 430 | Fred |
| 663 | Banty |
| 547 | Shon |
| 900 | Crio |
| 87 | Arif |
| 546 | Zerin |
| 322 | Chris |
| 76 | Deory |

Seperate those values and put in different rows.
Please help me in doing this so that I can proceed further, and it will be really helpful if someone can mention the logic , how to think for this prblm.
Thanks in advance.

Let me know if ur facing any kind of difficulty in understanding the prblm

Comment: markdown tables should not be used for pandas data. It isn't useful to work with. Ideally it should be copyable data using the code blocks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split (explode) pandas dataframe string entry to separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows)

Comment: use split and explode to get them into multiple rows

Comment: @noah it helped but I didn't get my answer, anyway thnks for ur reply

Comment: @joe Ferndz thanks fr yr reply, I will do a study on split and explode for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to Divyaansh's solution. Just use split, explode and merge.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'E_no':['6654-0984','430','663/547/900','87','546', '322,76'],
                    'E_name':['Elvin-Johnson','Fred','Banty/Shon/Crio','Arif','Zerin','Chris,Deory']})

#explode each column
x = df['E_no'].str.split('[,-/]').explode().reset_index(drop=True)
y = df['E_name'].str.split('[,-/]').explode().reset_index(drop=True)

#Merge both the columns together
df2 = pd.merge(x,y,left_index=True,right_index=True)
   
#print the modified dataframe
print (df2)
```

Output of this will be:

Original Dataframe:

```
          E_no           E_name
0    6654-0984    Elvin-Johnson
1          430             Fred
2  663/547/900  Banty/Shon/Crio
3           87             Arif
4          546            Zerin
5       322,76      Chris,Deory
```

Modified Dataframe:

```
   E_no   E_name
0  6654    Elvin
1  0984  Johnson
2   430     Fred
3   663    Banty
4   547     Shon
5   900     Crio
6    87     Arif
7   546    Zerin
8   322    Chris
9    76    Deory
```

Alternate, you can also create a new dataframe with the values from x and y.

```
x = df['E_no'].str.split('[,-/]').explode().reset_index(drop=True)

y = df['E_name'].str.split('[,-/]').explode().reset_index(drop=True)

#Create a new dataframe with the new values from x and y
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'E_no':x,'E_name':y})

print (df3)
```

Same result as before.

Or this:

```
#explode each column
x = df['E_no'].str.split('[,-/]').explode().reset_index()
y = df['E_name'].str.split('[,-/]').explode().reset_index()

#Create a new dataframe with the new values from x and y
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'E_no':x['E_no'],'E_name':y['E_name']})

print (df3)
```

Or you can do:

```
#explode each column
x = df['E_no'].str.split('[,-/]').explode().reset_index(drop=True)

y = df['E_name'].str.split('[,-/]').explode().reset_index(drop=True)

df4 = pd.DataFrame([x,y]).T

print (df4)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), [flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists), recombine, rename:

```
a = [item for sublist in df.E_no.str.split('\W').tolist() for item in sublist]
b = [item for sublist in df.E_name.str.split('\W').tolist() for item in sublist]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a, b)), columns=df.columns)
```

Output:

```
   E_no   E_name
0  6654    Elvin
1  0984  Johnson
2   430     Fred
3   663    Banty
4   547     Shon
5   900     Crio
6    87     Arif
7   546    Zerin
8   322    Chris
9    76    Deory
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide multiple delimiter in the `read_csv` arguments.

```
pd.read_csv("filepath",sep='-|/|,| ')
```

This is the best I can help right now without the data tables.

Comment: thanks for the reply bro, but would it bring those seperated values in different rows? What I think is it will only remove symbols like dashes, comma , slash etc

Comment: This won't work. It will make more columns, not more rows. This is not what OP wants

Answer (score 0):

I think this is actually rather tricky. Here's a solution in which we use the `E_no` column to build a column of regexes that we will then use to split the two original columns into parts. Finally we construct a new DataFrame from those parts. This method ensures that the second column's format matches the first's.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    [
        {"E_no": "6654-0984", "E_name": "Elvin-Johnson"},
        {"E_no": "430", "E_name": "Fred"},
        {"E_no": "663/547/900", "E_name": "Banty/Shon/Crio"},
        {"E_no": "87", "E_name": "Arif"},
        {"E_no": "546", "E_name": "Zerin"},
        {"E_no": "322,76", "E_name": "Chris,Deory"},
        {"E_no": "888+88", "E_name": "FIRST+SEC|OND"},
        {"E_no": "999|99", "E_name": "TH,IRD|FOURTH"},
    ]
)


def get_pattern(e_no, delimiters=None):
    if delimiters is None:
        delimiters = "-/,|+"

    delimiters = "|".join(re.escape(d) for d in delimiters)
    non_match_delims = f"(?:(?!{delimiters}).)*"
    delim_parts = re.findall(f"{non_match_delims}({delimiters})", e_no)

    pattern_parts = []
    for delim_part in delim_parts:
        delim = re.escape(delim_part)
        pattern_parts.append(f"((?:(?!{delim}).)*)")
        pattern_parts.append(delim)
    pattern_parts.append("(.*)")

    return "".join(pattern_parts)


def extract_items(row, delimiters=None):
    pattern = get_pattern(row["E_no"], delimiters)
    nos = re.search(pattern, row["E_no"]).groups()
    names = re.search(pattern, row["E_name"]).groups()
    return (nos, names)


nos, names = map(
    lambda L: [e for tup in L for e in tup],
    zip(*df.apply(extract_items, axis=1))
)

print(pd.DataFrame({"E_no": nos, "E_names": names}))

    E_no  E_names
0   6654    Elvin
1   0984  Johnson
2    430     Fred
3    663    Banty
4    547     Shon
5    900     Crio
6     87     Arif
7    546    Zerin
8    322    Chris
9     76    Deory
10   888    FIRST
11    88  SEC|OND
12   999   TH,IRD
13    99   FOURTH
```

Comment: hey mate thanks fr yr reply, I really loved ur user name..lol :) well I'm not very expert in python so your answer really goes straight and jumped out of my head. I will give a run to this code in morning and will get back if I face any challenges. But I'm hoping it will run smoothly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach to this:

1)Replace -&/ with comma(,) for both columns

2)Split each field on comma(,) then expand it and then stack it.

3)Resetting the index of each data frame which gives below DF

[image]
4) Finally merging two DF's into one finalDF

```
a={'E_no':['6654-0984','430','663/547/900','87','546','322,76'],
'E_name':['Elvin-Johnson','Fred','Banty/Shon/Crio','Arif','Zerin','Chris,Deory']}

df = pd.DataFrame(a)

df1=df['E_no'].str.replace('-|/',',').str.split(',',expand=True).stack().reset_index()

df2=df['E_name'].str.replace('-|/',',').str.split(',',expand=True).stack().reset_index()

df1.drop(['level_0','level_1'],axis=1,inplace=True)

df1.rename(columns={0:'E_no'},inplace=True)

df2.drop(['level_0','level_1'],axis=1,inplace=True)

df2.rename(columns={0:'E_name'},inplace=True)

finalDF=pd.merge(df1,df2,left_index=True,right_index=True)
```

Output:

[image]